# Text value stay same after value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four text fields where the user inserts values. For the top two input fields, it does a calculation of adding both fields together. The idea is to get the percentage value of each of those fields. So once there is a value, we divide by the total and then multiple by 100 to get the percentage value for each text field.

This all works fine!

However, if the user manually goes in and adds a day percentage, it should automatically calculate the night percentage (or the other way around) just by getting the value and subtracting by 100.

Every time I change the value, it reverts to the old version.

```js
var day_value, night_value, day_percentage, night_percentage;

$('#day_kwh').on('input', function() {
  day_value = this.value;
});

$('#night_kwh').on('input', function() {
  night_value = this.value;
});

$('.storage').on('change', function() {
  //console.log(day_value + night_value);
  if (typeof day_value != 'undefined' && typeof night_value != 'undefined') {
    total = parseInt(day_value) + parseInt(night_value);
    console.log('total value: ' + total);
    day_value = (day_value / total) * 100;
    console.log('day value: ' + day_value);
    night_value = (day_value / total) * 100;
    console.log('night value: ' + night_value);

    $('#day_percent').val(day_value);
    $('#night_percent').val(night_value);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="storage">
  Day kWH:
  <input type="text" name="day_kwh" id="day_kwh">
  <br>Night kWH:
  <input type="text" name="night_kwh" id="night_kwh">
  <br>Day %:
  <input type="text" name="day_percent" id="day_percent">
  <br>Night %:
  <input type="text" name="night_percent" id="night_percent">
  <br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Comment: I think you just forgot to change some of the variables, https://jsfiddle.net/1n4c6ja6/ seems to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AndrewBrooke It looks like it. The `day_value` & `night_value` are getting set on two different places meaning two different things.

Comment: 1. You are calling one general function to update the percents.  So when you change the percent fields, the same function runs.  2. You keep using the day_value and night_value fields to calculate the percents where you should have used the day_percent and night_percent variables.  That alone won't fix you problem, but it's a good start.  Let us know if you need more help, we can review and revise jsfiddle for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add extra code to check if the control who changed is day_percent

```
$('.storage').on('change', function(e) {
//console.log(day_value + night_value);
  if(e.target && $(e.target).attr('id') == 'day_percent'){
    /* Write the logic for your calculation you want */
  }
  else
   if (typeof day_value != 'undefined' && typeof night_value != 'undefined')  {
  total = parseInt(day_value) + parseInt(night_value);
  console.log('total value: ' + total);
  day_percentage = (day_value / total) * 100;
  console.log('day value: ' + day_value);
  night_percentage = (night_value / total) * 100;
  console.log('night value: ' + night_value);

  $('#day_percent').val(day_percentage);
  $('#night_percent').val(night_percentage);

  }
});
```